# Invoking MSAL sign in from static HTML page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using Azure AD B2C to manage authentication in my `ReactJs` SPA app and the `MSAL.js` library to manage `jwt` tokens, authentication, etc. which works nicely.

I also have a static HTML page that sits in front of the SPA app but not a part of it. This HTML page is just a nicely designed landing page for general public and it must exist for marketing purposes.

I need to invoke `MSAL` sign in from this HTML page so that I have a nice and smooth login experience. Currently, the login button on the HTML page simply redirects the user to a protected area in my `ReactJs` app. When the user hits the SPA app which is protected, `MSAL` kicks in and automatically redirects the user to Azure AD B2C login page which works fine but the experience is ugly. That's why I want to invoke the sign in process from the HTML page. I could use some help with this.

Here's what I've done so far:

First, I created a reference to `MSAL.js` in the HTML page using the following:

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/0.1.3/js/msal.min.js"></script>
```

I then added a `<script>` section within the HTML page to add the necessary Azure AD B2C tenant info. These are the same parameters I'm using in the `ReactJs` app:

```
<script>
   var instance = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/';
   var tenant = 'myazureadb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com';
   var signInPolicy = 'B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn';
   var applicationId = 'my-application-id';
   var scopes = ['https://myazureadb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/webclient/readaccess'];
   var redirectUri = 'https://example.com/member';

   // My function to redirect user to Azure AD B2C sign in/sign up page
   var mySignInFunction() {

       // What's next here?
   };

</script>
```

I think the last step will be to add an `onClick()` function to the button on my HTML page.

```
<button onClick="mySignInFunction()">Click here to login</button>
```

I'd appreciate some help in filling in the blanks here, in particular the sign in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the `mySignInFunction` function, you create an `Msal.UserAgentApplication` instance:

```
var authority = `${instance}${tenant}/${signInPolicy}`;

var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
  applicationId,
  authority,
  function (errorDescription, token, error, tokenType) {
    // Called if error has occurred.
  },
  {
    redirectUri: redirectUri
  });
```

Inside the `mySignInFunction` function, you then invoke the `Msal.UserAgentApplication.loginRedirect` function:

```
clientApplication.loginRedirect(scopes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's almost working. The only thing that's not working is the redirectUri part where once autenticated, I'm sent back to where I came from i.e. `https://example.com` as opposed to `https://example.com/member`. When I inspect the `clientApplication` object, I see that the redirectUri is there correctly. I pretty much copied and pasted your code except `var authority = \`${instance}{tenant}/{signInPolicy}\`;`. It wasn't parsing tenant and signInPolicy so I changed it to `var authority = \`${instance}${tenant}/${signInPolicy}\`;`

Comment: Thank you, @Sam, I have fixed the `authority` error in the above answer. The *redirect* URI should be set to an app endpoint that hosts MSAL.js to handle the authentication response. By default, MSAL,js then returns the signed-in user to the original URL. You might be able to overwrite this *return* URL by [setting the `msal.angular.login.request` key in the session storage](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/720b5a94742ab75e6ef620a8d7bba25b493c416b/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L356) before you call the `MSAL.UserAgentApplication.loginRedirect` function.

Comment: Don't you think this is a bug? Clearly a `redirectUri` was defined in `msal.js` but it has no effect. I posted a question on the Github repo. In the meantime, I tried saving it session storage but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Have you set https://example.com/member as a valid redirect url against your clientid in the Azure B2C settings?

Comment: @PaulHatcher Yes, it is set. If I invoke the login process by trying to hit a protected area, such as example.com/member, I do get redirected to that path after signing in and everything works fine. I'm just trying to invoke the login from a static landing page and get redirected to the protected member area and make the experience nice and user friendly.

Comment: I posted this as a potential bug on GitHub at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/320 and looks like my invocation may not be correct. I'm not seeing `id_token` in the URL after the login. Instead I'm seeing something like this: `http://localhost:49065/member#state=c78021f1-e91b-490c-a6eb-f361d0b81594&client_info=eyJ1aWQiOiIzNzM3MT...`. What does that mean?

Comment: This isn't a bug. It's by design. The "redirect" URI is the application callback to which the authentication response is returned. You are referring to a "return" URI to which the application callback returns control after handling the authentication response. Note: You must reference MSAL.js v0.1.6 to use the `msal.angular.login.request` key.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I'm a bit confused about redirect vs return. I now reference v0.1.6. How do I then specify the "return" URI so that I can invoke the login from the landing page but send the user to my SPA at `https://example.com/member` and not back to the landing page?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett - FYI, MSAL.js added a new feature to control navigating the original URL.  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/releases/tag/0.1.5.  See `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` option.